# How can I source a shell script using Go?

Tags: bash, shell, go

I want to source shell scripts using Go. Ideally the following code

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "source", file.Name())
```

but, I know that "source" is a bash built-in function, not an executable.

However, I have found some ways to mimic this behavior in Python:

http://pythonwise.blogspot.fr/2010/04/sourcing-shell-script.html

Unfortunately, I don't know how to translate this in Go. Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can't. "Sourcing" is only possible within the shell process.

Comment: BTW, *please* don't do anything like this in "real" code. At least not without *massive warnings*. Shell scripts can of course have arbitrary side effects, I can't think of any easy safe way to do this with a shell script but there are easy safe alternatives that cover almost all the use cases I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for your warning and concerns. I should have explain what I want to do. I'm trying to initialize my shell with a Go program. So I have to copy/link some dotfiles and source some others. That's why side effects are expected in my case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set environmental variables when running a program using `exec`:

```
cmd := exec.Command("whatever")
cmd.Env = []string{"A=B"}
cmd.Run()
```

If you really need source then you can run your command through bash:

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "source " + file.Name() + " ; echo 'hi'")
cmd.Run()
```

Check out this library for a more full-featured workflow: https://github.com/progrium/go-basher.

**Update**: Here's an example that modifies the current environment:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    err := ioutil.WriteFile("example_source", []byte("export FOO=bar; echo $FOO"), 0777)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "source example_source ; echo '<<<ENVIRONMENT>>>' ; env")
    bs, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    s := bufio.NewScanner(bytes.NewReader(bs))
    start := false
    for s.Scan() {
        if s.Text() == "<<<ENVIRONMENT>>>" {
            start = true
        } else if start {
            kv := strings.SplitN(s.Text(), "=", 2)
            if len(kv) == 2 {
                os.Setenv(kv[0], kv[1])
            }
        }
    }
}

log.Println(os.Getenv("FOO"))
```

Comment: Your sample works well for updating the environment of the run command, but it doesn't affect the current execution context of the Go program. See: http://beta.42grounds.io/s/7fa5ab8ec1b1e57d5b13ca9b71f3b4e1b107da4b11be01fb87c74893e12b2508

Comment: @Pith, use play.golang.org for linking to Go code, your link is completely unreadable. E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/asAcntp-j8

Comment: I don't understand why you find it unreadable. But why I didn't use the Go playground, is because the script doesn't run in the Go playground. Unlike the link I posted which run the script in a container.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently added such a utility function to my shell/bash Golang library:

https://godoc.org/mvdan.cc/sh/shell#SourceFile

For example, you could do:

```
vars, err := shell.SourceFile("foo.sh")
if err != nil { ... }
fmt.Println(vars["URL"].Value)
// http://the.url/value
```

It's decently safe, because it never actually calls bash nor any other program. It parses the shell script, then interprets it. But when interpreting, it has a whitelist of what files the script can open and what programs the script can execute.

The interpreter also has a context.Context, so you can set a timeout if you want to be protected against forever loops or other bad code.